# Get object identifier of Microsoft account from shared tenant (9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

Is there a way to get value of "objectIdentifier" claim for Microsoft account?

Case: I have an app with one form field, email (need's to be Microsoft account). When this email is entered, server (back end) need's to find out value of object identifier (user ID) in [common tenant for all Microsoft accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens) (section "tid").

Normally, if this was normal tenant in Azure Active Directory I would create Azure AD app and generated client secret for accessing Graph API, directory endpoint. Unfortunately, this is "special" tenant and I don't know is there any API I can call (as application) to get id of user (best option would be GetUserIdByEmail(email)).

I understand this is weird case but life is hard :)

Asking user to login and then retrieving value from token is not an option!

Comment: I'm _pretty sure_ to get the oid of an MS personal account, you _have to_ log them in

Comment: I though so. Ok, I will try to find some workaround. Thanks for quick feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API that I'm aware of where you could query for MS personal accounts' info without logging a user in.

If you think about it, it would be quite an easy source of building a user list for attacks :)

You will need to log them in to get their id, I don't think you can know it in advance.

Comment: I agree, but I had to check :)

Comment: Old question, but when you do log the user in, you can get the id by making a get request to the ``/me`` endpoint of the Microsoft Graph